# Rounding digits javascript - math

Tags: javascript, math, google-maps

I have the below in a google map application and want to display the elevation converted to feet but how do I round up/down to the nearest number? (eliminate digits after the decimal)  I tried the `number.toFixed(x)` method but nothing seemed to do it.

```
function getElevation(event) {

    var locations = [];
    var clickedLocation = event.latLng;
    locations.push(clickedLocation);
    var positionalRequest = { 'locations': locations }

    // Initiate the location request
    elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {

        // Retrieve the first result
        if (results[0]) {

          // Open an info window indicating the elevation at the clicked position
          infowindow.setContent("The elevation at this point <br/>is " + results[0].elevation*(3.2808399) + " feet.");
          infowindow.setPosition(clickedLocation);
          infowindow.open(map);
        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Elevation service failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to round to the nearest integer, simply use `Math.round(x)`

```
Math.round(25.9)  //returns 26
Math.round(25.2)  //returns 25
Math.round(-2.58) //returns -3
```

You may also want to look into `Math.floor` (always rounds down), and `Math.ceil` (always rounds up).

I've put together a Fiddle that demonstrates all three methods: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkXvm/)

Comment: Thanks man.  Ended up with `Math.round(results[0].elevation*(3.2808399)) + " feet.")`

Answer (score 1):

`Math.floor(n)`

Returns the number rounded down to the nearest integer

`Math.ceil(n)`

Returns the number rounded up to the nearest integer

`Math.round(n)`

Returns the number rounded up to the nearest integer